# Parse HTML and replace nodeValues based on charOffset

Tags: php, html, xpath, str-replace

I want to parse some HTML with the PHP DOM Parser and replace the text in some of the nodes.

HTML example:

```
<html><body><div id="content">blablabla</div><div id="article"><p id ="p2">some text here <a href="#"> text 2</a> <a href="#" id="finish"> text 3 </a></p></div></body></html>
```

I want to replace the text starting from `#p2` with character offset of 2, i.e. starting `"me text here "` to element with id `#finish` (character offset 0,i.e. replacing from the first character of that node).

I have the XPath of the start element, i.e. `#p2`, which is `XPathStart = ' /html/body/div/p '`

And the XPath of the end element, i.e. `#finish` which is `XPathEnd = ' /html/body/div/p/a[2] '`

The end result is that only text within that XPath and character offset range will be replaced.

Replacement text is stored in a database and can be: "Winter is a great season".

Result:

```
<html><body><div id="content">blablabla</div><div id="article"><p id ="p2">soWinter is a <a href="#"> great </a> <a href="#" id="finish"> season </a></p></div></body></html>
```

Comment: How do you define what text goes in the links?? Anyway, better xpaths for you: `//*[@id='p2']` and `//*[@id='finish']` ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks. The XPaths are not really the problem, think of it as pseudo code. I have the right Xpaths in my application. The issue is looping over the specified range of XPaths and charOffsets ..

Comment: and replacing with text from the DB at the right places